# Disqus api: count the number of comments on each page of my blog

Tags: api, disqus

I would like to create a list with the number of comments on each page of my blog.

Is possible with the Disqus API?
There is a call that counts comments starting from the URL of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Disqus API has an endpoint called `threads/list` which returns the details for a thread, including the number of comments. You can learn about this method here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/list/

You can see a code example illustrating how to use the endpoint here: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/php/get-thread-details.php